# Error when pushing a python app to bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, buildpack

When I try cf push from local app dir, I get the following error, seems to be related to python buildpack.
Error:

```
`2016-03-31T21:08:07.00-0400 [STG/185] OUT -----> Downloaded app package (6.7M)
2016-03-31T21:08:07.98-0400 [STG/0] OUT -------> Buildpack version 1.5.1
2016-03-31T21:08:09.86-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing runtime (requests
2016-03-31T21:08:09.86-0400 [STG/0] OUT python-2.7.9)
2016-03-31T21:08:10.32-0400 [STG/0] OUT ! Resource https://lang-python.s3.amazonaws.com/cedar/runtimes/requests
2016-03-31T21:08:10.32-0400 [STG/0] OUT python-2.7.9.tar.gz is not provided by this buildpack. Please upgrade your buildpack to receive the latest resources.
2016-03-31T21:08:10.33-0400 [STG/0] OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
2016-03-31T21:08:10.33-0400 [STG/0] ERR
2016-03-31T21:08:12.29-0400 [API/3] ERR encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase`
```

Here is my manifest.yml:

```
applications:
- services:
  - dialog-pizza
  - nlc_weather
  - Retrieve and Rank-p4
  path: .
  memory: 128M
  instances: 1
  domain: mybluemix.net
  name: jklab
  host: jklab
  disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpack: python_buildpack
```

here is my runtime.txt

```
requests
python-2.7.9
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `runtime.txt` file should have only the python version you want to use and you need to remove the `requests` word from it:

```
python-2.7.9
```

The error you are having is because the buildpack is trying to find a python version named `requests python-2.7.9` and it does not exist.

Comment: Indeed, the line, "requests", belongs in the `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: @joe4k if this solves your issue please accept the answer